# Loop thought a multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I try to return a multidimensional array into a function to iterate it but I'm not sure what's wrong with my logic

```
const arr = [[1,2], [3,4],[5,6]]
```

```
for(let i = 0; i < thirdInterval.length-1; i++){
    getNumbers(thirdInterval[i], thirdInterval[i+1])
}
```

The result that I want to achieve is return the first element into the first argument of the function and the second element of the array into the second argument of the function.

Comment: Post full code. What are you doing with arr

Comment: What is the expect output of your loop asuming that `getNumber` logs the elements

Comment: What do you mean by "first element"? Do you mean the current element of the outer array or do you mean the first element of the inner array? At the moment you are passing the current element of the outer array (which is itself an array of length 2) to the function.

Comment: Also, is `arr` the same as `thirdInterval`? Why are they named differently? Please be as clear as possible when posting code. We shouldn't have to assume anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is looping through the array and getting only the array at the index i, e.g `arr[0]` which is `[1,2]`. and `(thirdInterval[i], thirdInterval[i+1])` is actually equals to `([1,2], [3,4])`

to access the first and second elements you should address them like the following:

```
for(let i = 0; i < thirdInterval.length-1; i++){
    getNumbers(thirdInterval[i][0], thirdInterval[i][1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [[1,2][3,4][5,6]];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++;) {
    func(arr[i][0], arr[i][1];
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting answers with only code. A description helps people understand why your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating an array with sub-arrays, which means that `thirdInterval[i]` contains two items. You can get the items using the indexes `thirdInterval[i][0]` and `thirdInterval[i][1]`, but since you're calling a function with those values, you can use spread instead - `getNumbers(...thirdInterval[i])`.

In addition, the loop's condition should be `i < thirdInterval.length` if you don't want to skip the last item.

**Demo:**

```js
const thirdInterval = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

const getNumbers = console.log // mock getNumbers

for (let i = 0; i < thirdInterval.length; i++) {
  getNumbers(...thirdInterval[i])
}
```